# HTML styling of labels

Tags: html

I have used two labels and used `<br/>` between them. But I want them to share the same color so that the br is invisible.
Eg. 
If label are coloured yellow, then the full block should be yellow and the line separating them should not be visible

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code, so some one can help you. Also this article can help you write better questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why would there be a line separating them, and why would such a non-existent line be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `class` for the whole `div`.

**NOTE :** `<br>` is invisible by default.

```css
.yellow{
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='yellow'>
    <label>Label one</label> 
    <br/>
    <label>Label Two</label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are saying: You can wrap the labels and br in a div and then set the color yellow on the div instead of on the labels itself.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```css
label{display:block;}
.red label{background-color:red;}
.blue label{background-color:blue;}
.yellow label{background-color:yellow;}
.yellow br{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <label>name</label><br>
  <label>age</label>
 </div>

<div class="blue">
  <label>name</label><br>
  <label>age</label>
 </div>

<div class="yellow">
  <label>name</label><br>
  <label>age</label>
 </div>
```